# How to get more than 100 rows using Airtable API using offest?

Tags: api, pagination, python-requests, airtable

I am really new to the Airtable API and for some reason connecting the API this way did not work.

```
at = airtable.Airtable('Base_Key', 'Airtable_Key')
```

But I got it working this way -

```
get_url = ‘https://api.airtable.com/v0/BASE_ID/TABLE_NAME’
get_headers = {
‘Authorization’: ‘Bearer API_KEY’ }

Response = requests.get(get_url, headers=get_headers)
Response_Table = Response.json()
```

However, this fetches only the first 100 records and am reading about offset and pagination but I am unable to figure how to incorporate it into this code.

Thank you for the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of issues, I found this solution. Posting it for anyone else facing the same problem.

```
global offset
offset = '0'
result = []

while True :
    url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/BASE_ID/TABLE_NAME"
    querystring = {
        "view":"Published View",
        "api_key":"YOUR_KEY",
        "offset": offset}

    try :
        response= requests.get(url, params=querystring)
        response_Table = response.json()
        records = list(response_Table['records'])
        result.append(records)
        #print(records[0]['id'] , len(records))

        try : 
            offset = response_Table['offset']
            #print(offset)

        except Exception as ex:
            #print(ex , offset)
            break

    except error as e:
        print(e)
```